# Add additional data to tooltip in iOS which does not belongs to x&y-axis of graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts, tooltip

I followed this demo to draw Column charts.
(https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/column-rotated-labels).

What Issue I am facing is : I can easily show x-axis and y-axis information in tooltip. But I am not able to put additional information in tooltip from a different array (suppose array for depicting required qty for item).

I tried to do like this ;

tooltip.pointFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velocity : {point.y:.2f} 
Remaining Quantity : %@",RemainingQtyArray];
It will print whole array in tooltip.
tooltip.pointFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velocity : {point.y:.2f} 
Remaining Quantity : %@",RemainingQtyArray[i++]];
It will print last item from array.
So, how can i put additional info so that when anyone taps on graph, it will show this info too.

[image]
**Want tooltip like this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sarjr1d/1) demo in JS

Tooltip in JS way

```
 tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2017: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b><br>Extra One: <b>{point.data1}</b><br>Extra Two: <b>{point.data2}</b>'
    },
```

Series data in JS way

```
data: [
        {name:'Shanghai', y:24.2,data1:'Aa',data2:'Ba'},
        {name:'Beijing', y:20.2,data1:'Ab',data2:'Bb'},
        {name:'Karachi', y:14.2,data1:'Ac',data2:'Bc'},
        {name:'Shenzhen', y:13.2,data1:'Ad',data2:'Bd'},
    ],
```

Through [doc](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/column-rotated-labels) I  convert into ios.

For ios

```
HITooltip *tooltip = [[HITooltip alloc]init];
tooltip.pointFormat = @"Population in 2017: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b><br>Extra One: {point.data1}<br>Extra Two: {point.data2}";
```

For ios series data

```
column.data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @{
                      @"name":@"Shanghai",
                      @"y":@23.7,
                      @"data1":@'Aa',
                      @"data2":@'Ba'
                     },
                   @{
                      @"name":@"Shanghai",
                      @"y":@16.1,
                      @"data1":@'Aa',
                      @"data2":@'Ba'
                     },
                   @{
                      @"name":@"Karachi",
                      @"y":@14.2,
                      @"data1":@'Aa',
                      @"data2":@'Ba'
                     },
                   @{
                      @"name":@"Shenzhen",
                      @"y":@14,
                      @"data1":@'Aa',
                      @"data2":@'Ba'
                     }
                   , nil];
```

Comment: I am unable to draw graph with this format of "column.data". In doc it is constituting arrays not dictionaries. like this column.data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@[
                                                     @"Shanghai",
                                                     @23.7
                                                     ],

Comment: For extra data in tooltip  to work it has to be dictionaries only (array of objects in JS)

Comment: I did like this as u told but graph is not drawing (coming as blank)with this format.

Comment: are you able to plot https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/column-drilldown it also uses dictionaries.